# find decile bounds for each group in r

Tags: r, quantiles

Let's say that I have two variables: `x1` is numeric and `x2` is factor. I need to find the upper and lower value for each decile of `x1` by `x2` group.

Example,

```
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rnorm(100, 10, 2)
x2 <- ceiling(runif(100, min=0, max=3))

df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
df$x2 <- as.factor(df$x2)
```

To find the decile bounds for `x1`, one can simple do:

```
df$DecileBounds <- cut2(df$x1, g=10)
```

Comment: Like this: `with(df, tapply(x1, x2, quantile, c(0.1, 0.9)))`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot what I need is the upper and lower bound for each decile. For example, when x2 = 1, i need 10 intervals, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two solutions

**First**

```
result=by(df$x1, df$x2, function(x) cut2(x, g=10))
```

Note that in the code above the object `result` is a list with 3 elements, each being composed of the decile bounds of `x1` corresponding to each unique level in `x2`.

**Second**

```
library(dplyr)
result<-df%>%group_by(x2)%>%mutate(DecileBounds=cut2(x1, g=10))
```

The object `result` above is a data frame with 3 columns, the first of which is `x1` the second is `x2` and the third is the corresponding decile interval.